# scipy.optimize.minimize doesn't work

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying the optimization function `scipy.optimize.minimize` in Python. From the result, it does not work. Here is a part of my code. I just want to minimize the sum of square of difference of two values.

```
def calibrate(x):
    # Real equity value and equity volatility from market data
    equity_val = 30.0
    equity_vol = 0.556       
    diff_s = 10000*(geske(x)[0]-equity_val)**2
    diff_vol = 10000*(geske(x)[1]-equity_vol)**2
    diff = diff_s+diff_vol
    return diff
# Here geske is a function defined before, which takes two input parameter and returns several values

bnds = ((0,None), (0,None))
opt = sco.minimize(calibrate, [100,0.3], method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds)
```

However, the result of `opt` is as follows:

[image]

From the result, it seems that the optimization function does not work, it just returns the initial guess value I gave. Why? Is there somewhere I made mistakes in my calibrate function?

Comment: It is possible that your guess simply is the minimum. I would test out some values, but you haven't included the `geske` function.

Comment: In the function I want to minimize, it is the sum of square of difference. Therefore the minimum value should be zero. Besides, The function I call to minimize is "calibrate", which will call geske function.

Comment: Well, without the function there really is no way to help. Minimization functions display a wide range of odd behaviors.

Comment: One interesting piece. The jacobian `jac` returned is all zeros. This would seem to indicate it is at a local extrema or `geske` is returning constant values that are not varying with different inputs. Is `geske` a smooth, continuous function?

Comment: @DavidMaust - good point? And why is the Jacobian length 3? For a 2D problem it should be a different size and shape I would think.

Comment: My guess is that the OP is trying to use `minimize` to solve a discrete problem.